# SelectMultipleHelpTextRemovalMixin yields "Cannot create a consistent method resolution"

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I'm using Django 1.6 with django-autocomplete-light 2.0.0a15 and am trying to remove the `Hold down "Control", or "Command" on a Mac, to select more than one.` string in my forms.

According to the documentation (https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/v2/faq.html#how-to-work-around-django-bug-9321-hold-down-control), I should use `SelectMultipleHelpTextRemovalMixin` in my form definition.

I tried the following:

```
import autocomplete_light
autocomplete_light.autodiscover()

from django import forms
from .models import SomeModel

class CreatePatFromEidForm(autocomplete_light.SelectMultipleHelpTextRemovalMixin, autocomplete_light.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
```

... but this yields:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases ModelForm, SelectMultipleHelpTextRemovalMixin
```

Any idea what this is due to?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation link you posted says:

> Just use the autocomplete_light.ModelForm **or** inherit from both SelectMultipleHelpTextRemovalMixin and django.forms.ModelForm.

If using `autocomplete_light.ModelForm` then you don't need to use `SelectMultipleHelpTextRemovalMixin` manually ;)

Comment: Thanks @jpic. I tried that, but still the text was being displayed. 
Apparently this is due to my `LANGUAGE_CODE` set to `nl-BE` (I actually get "`Houd "Control", of "Command" op een Mac, ingedrukt om meerdere te selecteren.`" as string). When I change over to `en-US`, the text disappears.
What would be the most effective way to keep
 my language code and to remove the string?

Comment: Oops, seems like you have found a bug in SelectMultipleHelpTextRemovalMixin !

Comment: OK - I'll open a new issue on the Github's project page.